# Warning Error on Datatable with My Gridview

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview

Here is my code using jQuery Datatable

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#<%=grdEmployee.ClientID%>").dataTable();
    })
</script>
```

Here is My GridView Code

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdEmployee" runat="server" PageSize="5" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnPageIndexChanging="grdEmployee_PageIndexChanging" AllowPaging="true" AllowSorting="true">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Emp ID" SortExpression="Emp ID">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblEmpID" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Empid") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Emp Name" SortExpression="Emp Name">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblEmpName" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("EmpName") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Emp Salary" SortExpression="Emp Salary">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblEmpSalary" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Salary") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkEdit" runat="server" Text="Edit" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("Empid") %>' CommandName="eEdit"></asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDelete" runat="server" Text="Delete" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("Empid") %>' CommandName="eDelete"></asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

When I set GridView page size property to 5, it will give me a data table warning.

My database has 9 records and when I change the pagesize value from 5 to 10, it will not return any warning.

Comment: What exactly is the warning?

Comment: Post also your gridview code

Comment: I have reformatted your code and fixed a few grammatical errors. Make sure to look at the "preview" window before posting.

Comment: Neps The error is 

DataTables warning: table id=grdEmployee - Requested unknown parameter '1' for row 10. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4

Comment: Thanks J.F for Reformatted My Code..